# how to change the space between inside a slide

Tags: beamer

I am trying a presentation

```
\documentclass[11pt] {beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[h!]
 I have a sentence here  \footnote{\tiny I have a reference here \vspace{1.5ex}} 
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=0.5\textheight]{photo1.png}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The sentence that I have is sitting on top of the figure. I want to know if I can somehow make a space between the figure and that sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually insert a `\vspace*{...}` between the sentence and the image.

Unrelated to the problem, but floating specifier such as `[h!]`, don't make sense in a document class that does not have a floating mechanism and figures are centred by default, so `\centering` is superfluous.

Also it is usually better to either specify the width or the height of an image, but not both at the same time, because this will very likely disturb the aspect ratio. If you really must specify both, add the `keepaspectratio` option.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
 I have a sentence here  \footnote{\tiny I have a reference here \vspace{1.5ex}} 

 \vspace*{1cm}
%\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=0.5\textheight, keepaspectratio]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]